# Run 2 python scripts in Google Colab

Tags: python, concurrency, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm using GPU on Google Collab. How can I run 2 python scripts simultaneously to get a continuous evaluation for my data?
I have tried

```
!python script1.py &
!python script2.py &
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this yet, however, with ipython you can run a python script simply as

run myscript.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [built-in magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics) `%%bash` as first line in your cell:

```
%%bash

python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```